# Перезаписать бинарный файл частями

Tags: python

имеется большой файл, его нужно перезаписать в новый файл по частям

```
f = open('archive.rar', 'rb')
while True:
    piece = f.read(512*1024)
    if not piece:
        break
    with open('new_archive.rar', "wb") as fOut:
        data = bytearray(piece)
        #do something
        fOut.write(data)
f.close()
```

Скрипт записывает первые 66kb и прекращает работу.

Как частями перезаписать в новый файл полностью?

Comment: Вы не верно делаете проверку на окончание файла,  ```if not piece:``` piece ,будет равно false не только в случае окончания данных, но так же и в тех случаях когда считаное значение совпадет со значением false, например если piece = 0 то это будет трактоваться как false....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140281/how-to-find-out-whether-a-file-is-at-its-eof

Comment: А почему вы решили, что скрипт не делает свою работу? Все он делает. Вот только вы каждый раз перезаписываете уже созданную часть архива заново. То есть, старый затирается, новый добавляется. Вам нужно добавить счетчик и записывать части архива с индексом. Тогда все будет хорошо.

Comment: @Евгений, скрипт сам прерывает свою работу по достижению 66 кб

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так, должно получиться:

```
f = open('archive.rar', 'rb')
data = f.read(512*1024)
while True:
    piece = f.read(512*1024)
    if not piece:
        break
    else:
        data = data + piece
with open(f'new_archive.rar', "wb") as fOut:
    fOut.write(data)
f.close()
```

Comment: нужен один перезаписанный файл, в таком случае их целая куча получается

Comment: Исправил. Вроде записывает все как надо. И даже архив читается после записи.)